# Array help | JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

im quite stuck on this.

How would i be able to take an item from my array and output it, but once
it runs again it'll choose another string within the array. such as

```
const myArray = [
    'me1',
    'me2'
];

console.log(myArray); = me1
next time i run the code 
console.log(myArray); = me2,
```

any ideas would be wonderful. thanks

Kind Regards,
Phil.

Comment: What do you mean by `next time i run the code`?

Comment: just take with array index myArray[0] or myArray[1]

Comment: maybe you want to use array.shift()

Comment: say i have the log connected to a button within my index and i click it, thats what i mean,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // values
const myArray = [
  'me1',
  'me2'
];

// previously selected values
var history = [];

/**
 * This function return a value from myArray that isn't in  
 * the history array that store previously selected values.
 * If history array contains all the values from myArray, it
 * resets history to an empty array to start over.
 */
const nextValue = ()=>{

  if (history.length === myArray.length) history = []

  let value = null;

  for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){

    const v = myArray[i];

    if (!history.includes(v)) {
      history.push(v);
      value = v;
      break;
    }
  }

  return value;
}

/**
 * Triggers nextValue()
 */
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){

 console.log(nextValue()) 
};
```

Comment: Actually. is there a way to loop this as its stopping after it reaches the last item in the array

Comment: while(myArray.length > 0){
      console.log(myArray.shift());
    }

Comment: just pauses after me2

Comment: Yes, because it's the last element remaining in the array, if you console.log(myArray) after that, it should be empty

Comment: any way to fix this? as i need it to return to me1 and continue its path

Comment: edit- it keeps returning me2, mind if we move this to PM?

Comment: Add small explanation even though code is explanatory

Comment: @Jayffe Please PM me i have a few more JS questions if thats ok, as well as i wana close this since your answer works

Comment: I don't know if we can pm on this site but i opened a room if you want https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80589/dopedealers

Comment: i'm trying to find a way

Comment: great thanks for all of your help btw! if you have discord i have that also

Comment: What is your discord tag ?

Comment: Phil#0004 is my tag

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first item everytime:

```
console.log(myArray.shift())
```

if you want to get a random item:

```
function random(arr){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
}
for(let i = 0; i< arr.length < i++){
  let index = random(arr)
  console.log(arr[index])
  arr.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shift() method as shown: 
`while(myArray.length > 0){
    console.log(myArray.shift());
}`

Comment: This method does work but as i stated with jayffe's comments it just ends as it is the last element in the array, is there any way i could possibly loop this function and only have it output once i send console.log again

Comment: You can use this code, replace the commented break with your break condition, currently the loop will go infinite.... `let tempArray = Object.assign([], myArray); while(tempArray.length > 0){ console.log(tempArray.shift()); if(tempArray.length === 0) tempArray = Object.assign([], myArray); //break condition }`

Comment: i tried a snippet of code like that, only kept bringing up the last item in the array

Comment: I checked that. It is giving the output: me1 me2 me1 me2... so on. Can you share your code snippet?